# Cumulative CPU time across reboots

Tags: cpu, monitoring, cpu-usage, statistics

**How can I record and view cumulative CPU time on system across reboots?** Essentially, it should be like the `TIME+` column of `top`, but not per process. In other words, like `vnstat`, but for CPU time. I am the only user on the system.

###### `vnstat`:

```
     daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     yesterday      4.30 MiB |    2.42 MiB |    6.72 MiB |    0.64 kbit/s
         today      2.03 MiB |    1.07 MiB |    3.10 MiB |    0.59 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     total          6.33 MiB |    3.49 MiB |    9.82 MiB |    0.62 kbit/s
```

###### Desired:

```
     daily
                     CPU time | % of day 
     -------------------------+-------
     2023-08-01         0 s    |  0.0%
     2023-08-02         0 s    |  0.0%
     2023-08-03         0 s    |  0.0%
     2023-08-04      1052 s    |  1.2%
     2023-08-05      7200 s    |  8.3%
     --------------------------+--------
     total           8252 s    |  4.8% (avg)
```

**I'm really only interested in the total CPU time and `CPU seconds ÷ seconds since monitoring started`.**

Comment: A/ What init system are you using ? B/ Do you actually want to realize this (logging + computation by yourself for let's say education purposes) or would you prefer some rock solid good old tool that would achieve what you want while being capable of much much more ?

Comment: @MC68020 A/ I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, so `systemd`. B/ Rock solid tool is preferred, but custom logging and computation is acceptable too.

Comment: What you want is called "process accounting", and must be configured and managed. Beware of producing BIG datafiles. Start with `man accton sa`

Comment: @waltinator I don't need/want the cumulative time of _processes_ though, only total (non-granular) system time. For example, 104 seconds at hour 1, 512 seconds at hour 2, etc. This shouldn't take too much space (at most 4 bytes per hour assuming it is stored as literal text. At 8760 hours per year, it takes only 35 KiB).

Comment: Monitoring "wall clock time" on a time sharing system like Unix/Linux is meaningless. Depending on system load, you could take any number of "wall clock seconds" to perform a given amount of work.

Comment: @waltinator as specified in my post, I am interested in the `TIME+` column of `top`, but cumulative across all processes ("system" CPU time). The only wall clock time I want is the time since the monitoring started.